# Is it possible to Remote Desktop to Console 0 of a remote XP SP3 machine using mstsc.exe /admin

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

Is it possible to Remote Desktop to Console 0 of a remote XP Pro SP3 machine from an XP Pro SP3 machine using mstsc.exe /admin? I am getting " ... maximum terminal connections reached ... " even with the /admin option.

I am starting to think that once the maximum terminal connections are reached on XP Pro SP3 it just won't let anyone remotely connect at all. Is this correct?

Comment: I have seen this when the connection is lost; after a while you sometimes realise you're on a second connection when there is a "connected" disconnected first connection. I haven't yet had it happen on a truely remote computer where I can't get someone to fix it.

Comment: I thought 1 was the maximum RDC to XP and it always takes over console.

Comment: @hyperslug: Not entirely correct. Yes, XP limits you to one active session, but it still has a "fast user switching" feature; if several users are logged in, only one can be on the zeroth winstation.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your thinking.  You have reached the maximum number of connections like it said.